# Error during running simu5G with INeT in omnet++

Tags: c++, omnet++, inet

I'm trying to run simu5G with omnet++ in omnet++ but it gives me this error:

> <!> Error: Cannot load library '../../../src//libsimu5g.dll': The specified module could not be found

Can you please help me to fix this error?

I tried to download omnet++ version 6.0 and simu5G 1.21
but no success.

Comment: where is that library?

Comment: in omnet++ software